# Sum of all odd and even digits

Tags: java

I have this program that finds the sum of odd and even digits in a parsed int as seen below. My program right now is finding the sum going right to left. How do I make it so it starts from the last digit (i.e left to right) instead?

```
    out.print("Please enter a number: ");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    int x = Integer.parseInt(s);
    int y = 0;
    int e = 0;
    int o = 0;
    while (x != 0) {
        y = x % 10;
        out.print(y + " ");
        if (y % 2 == 0) {
            e = e + y;
            out.print(e + " ");
        } else {
            o = o + y;
            out.print(o + " ");
        }
        x = x / 10;
    }
    out.println("sum of odd: " + o);
    out.println("sum of even: " + e);
```

---

I am sort of running in an infinite loop

```
      out.print("Please enter a number: ");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    double x = Integer.parseInt(s);
    double y = 0;
    double e = 0;
    double o = 0;
    double length = Math.pow(10, s.length() - 1);
    while (x != 0) {
        y = x / length;
        if (y % 2 == 0) {
            e = e + y;
        } else {
            o = o + y;
        }
        x = x % length;
    }
    out.println("sum of odd: " + o);
    out.println("sum of even: " + e);
```

Comment: Try something. Then tell us what went wrong.

Comment: Your program is actually going right to left.

Comment: You're already going right to left. Left to right is trickier.

Comment: @RohitJain I've fixed that part of the problem description.

Comment: @RohitJain yeah, I thought so. x%10 will give you the last digit.

Comment: @archer I take offence to that characterization. I prefer "Ahh, LAZY students".

Comment: It will be easier handling this using the original `String s` rather than working with the `int x`. Anyway, try something (as @Cruncher advices you) and explain the problems/errors you have so we can give precise help.

Comment: @Cruncher I didn't even know I was doing that already. Now I will figure out how to go left to right

Comment: The instructor should instead be asking students to implement an algorithm for converting arabic numerals 1 to 3999, to roman numerals, as one implementation depends on traversing a number's numeral from right to left.

Comment: @KennethFaried Start with a concrete example. Then generalize. For example, how would you find the leftmost digit of 43503? Divide it by 10000. Now how can you generalize that?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty. RIP, your students. LOL ;)

Comment: @Cruncher by 10000 you want to say.

Comment: @archer Oh dear, yes of course

Comment: If all you want is the sum of the digits, why do you care what order you get them in? Addition is commutative and associative.

Comment: Don't break the head of the student. He will spend all the night finding how to find the leftmost digit by dividing by 1000. ;)

Comment: A hint: you may know how many digits has a number by using this formula: (int)(log10(number)) + 1. Ex: log10(1) + 1 = 1, log10(9) + 1 = 1, log10(12345) + 1 = 5.

Comment: @DavidConrad professor said to find from left to right! ;)

Comment: My thoughts are: this is not possible to determine the number of decimal digits in the number without the loop. Am I right?

Comment: @archer check my last comment. Strangely, it only has 1 upvote =\

Comment: Got to agree with @LuiggiMendoza. I would have just iterated through the string from first to last char, or vice versa and converted the character to an integer, and gone from that. This has got academia written all over it.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson or even easier: use `theString.length()`. No need to iterate it.

Comment: Iterate as in loop through mate, though something like foreach(Char c in s) {} would be a nice way of expressing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the way you do your division.  Perhaps your loop could look like this:

```
// Figure out how many digits you have.  I'll leave that to you
int digits = ...;
for(int i = digits; i < 0; i--) {
    int currentDigit = (x / Math.exp(10, i-1)) % 10;

    // You have your digit, so the checking/summing happens here.
}
```

An example would be if you have the number 1234.  It has 4 digits, so the first iteration of the loop, i = 4.  So, the expression becomes:

```
int currentDigit = (1234 / 1000) % 10;
```

Which yields 1.  The second iteration would be:

```
int currentDigit = (1234 / 100) % 10;
```

Which yields 2.  The division truncates the right side of the number that you don't want to see, and the modulus truncates the left side that you don't want to see.